# how to continue run script after tail -f command

Tags: bash, signals, tail

I have the following script:

```
tail -f nohup.out
echo 5
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on `tail -f`, the script stops running: the `5` is not printed. How can I run the command `echo 5` after I stop the `tail` command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends the [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) signal to all the processes in the foreground [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). While `tail` is running, the process group consists of the `tail` process and the shell running the script.

Use the [`trap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/trap.html) builtin to override the default behavior of the signal.

```
trap " " INT
tail -f nohup.out
trap - INT
echo 5
```

The code of the trap does nothing, so that the shell progresses to the next command (`echo 5`) if it receives a SIGINT. Note that there is a space between the quotes in the first line; any shell code that does nothing will do, except an empty string which would mean to ignore the signal altogether (this cannot be used because it would cause `tail` to ignore the signal as well). The second call to `trap` restores the default behavior, so that after the third line a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will interrupt the script again.

Comment: Also there is the `screen` command which is similar to the `tmux` command. Try `man screen`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo 5" SIGINT SIGTERM
tail -f nohup.out
```

Comment: You can't trap SIGKILL, the SIGKILL here is ignored. This only prints `echo 5` if the shell receives a SIGINT or SIGTERM, not if `tail` exists for some other reason (because the file doesn't exist, or because `tail` is killed explicitly). You can add the pseudo-signal `EXIT`, but this is not a very readable way of specifying that `echo 5` is to be executed after `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just start the `tail` in a new shell, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -i -c 'tail -f nohup.out'
echo 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [rwos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11953396/4149210) , but adding inline trapping.

```
bash -i -c "trap ' ' SIGINT; tail -F '$1'; trap - SIGINT"
```

This would work without closing putty session when issuing subsequent SIGINT signals (that was my problem)

Answer (score 0):

In bash end the line with a single ampersand to run the command in the background in an async way

```
tail -f nohup.out &
```

Answer (score -1):

Look up File:Tail in perl, have used this a few times on different projects to automate tailing logs and carrying out a specific action for log output.

google ftp-upload-mon a project I uploaded to sourceforge which uses File:Tail to tail -f xferlogs